# <div> not using full bootstrap column space

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am trying to make three buttons use the full width of a column.

The grid is 3 for the buttons and 9 for other components.

Here's a [visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBoUp.jpg). So basically the buttons should also occupy the space that's marked with red, they should just use the whole column of 3.

Here's App.js where I imported the component:

```
<div className="container-full padding-0" style={{overflow:'hidden', overflowY:'hidden'}}>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-3" style={{borderRight:"1px solid #000"}}>
            <div className="row no-gutters mt-auto">
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <COMPONENT1/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-9">
                    <COMPONENT2/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <COMPONENT3 store={store} style={{overflow:'hidden'}}/>
            <COMPONENT4/>
            <BUTTONS/> --------------------------> Here are the buttons
       </div>
       <div className="col-sm-9" style={{paddingRight: 0, paddingLeft: 0}}>
            <COMPONENT6 = {store} style={{overflow:'hidden'}}/>
            <br/>
            <COMPONENT7/>
            <COMPONENT8 store={store} clicked={this.clicked}/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And buttons component:

```
<div className="row no-gutters mt-auto" style={{paddingTop:10}}>
    <div className="col-sm-4">
        <Button variant="raised" style={buttonStyle}>A</Button>
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-4">
        <Button variant="raised" style={buttonStyle}>B</Button>   
    </div>

    <div className="col-sm-4">
        <Button variant="raised" style={buttonStyle}>C</Button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css for the buttons:

```
const buttonStyle = {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    display:'inline-block',
    width:'100%',
    height:100
}
```

**EDIT: Here's a quick [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ckBJ.jpg) of the UI**

Comment: can you supply a JSFiddle or URL?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/92j3kv49wy) it is. Although it doesn't look like it's reading the bootstrap `classNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following method:

Give below css rules to `row no-gutters mt-auto`:

```
style={{ display: 'flex', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}
```

It will work for sure !

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I checked it in the codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/92j3kv49wy) and it was working here ...

Comment: I added `style={{paddingTop:10, display:'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}` to the `row no-gutters mt-auto` `div` and `flex: 0 0 33.33%` to all `<div className="col-sm-4" style={{height:100, flex: '0 0 33.33%'}}>` `divs`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Okay can you please try replacing my css codes with this `style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}` ? .. Add this to row no-gutters mt-auto

Comment: All the `<div>`s ?

Comment: No .. on this div `row no-gutters mt-auto`

Comment: and if that also don't work .. I just tried this in buttons.js
`<div className="row no-gutters mt-auto" style={{ display: 'flex', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>`
Just add display flex in that as well like I did in the above and it will work for sure ...

Comment: I really don't get it, since all the other components in the same column are using the whole space. This also didn't work - it has to be something with the component. Sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/GaUTwBj) you can really see what the problem is. Here's the [elements tab](https://imgur.com/a/u8NqL0b).